# Why do I need verify() when I already have expectOne()?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am learning Angular unit testing from some online courses.

Here is a part of the code.

```
  it("should find a course by id", () => {
    coursesService.findCourseById(12).subscribe((course) => {
      expect(course).toBeTruthy();
      expect(course.id).toBe(12);
    });
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne("/api/courses/12");

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");
    req.flush(COURSES[12]);

    httpTestingController.verify(); 

  });
```

The definition of `verify()` on the angular document is:

> Verify that no unmatched requests are outstanding.

I was wondering why I need to call `verify()` when I already called `expectOne()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`httpTestingController.verify();` is useful for cases when you want to verify that specific HTTP requests were not sent.

i.e. when there is conditional logic around an HTTP request.

```
// component.ts

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('my-api-request').subscribe(...);

    if (this.id != undefined) {
        this.http.get('my-additional-request').subscribe(...);
    }

}
```

```
// component.spec.ts

it("should only do one request when id does not exist", () => {
    this.component.id = 1;
    this.fixture.detectChanges();

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne("my-api-request");

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");
    req.flush({});

    // will fail since `id` is defined. Without this verify the test will pass.
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });
```

Comment: Hi @g0rb, thank you for your reply. So the expectOne('X') only cares about the URL "X". If we send another req, as long as "X" is not more than once, the testing will still pass, right?

Comment: And once we call verify(), any req which does not match expectOne() will fail the testing.

Comment: @NickLin yes, correct.